# "Invalid mock-up for internal class" in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, jmockit

I get these errors when I want run test to class with "RunWith(JMockit.class)". I'm using NetBeans 8.2, JUnit 4.12, Hamcrest 1.3 and JMockit 1.27. (I have to use these versions because of classes on studies...)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mock-up for internal class
>   org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier; remove it to avoid this
>   warning   at
>   junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:30)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mock-up for internal class
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner; remove it to avoid this
>   warning   at
>   junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:30)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mock-up for internal class
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod; remove it to avoid this
>   warning   at
>   junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:30)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033)